# What does the TFS Scheduled Backup Tool do that a database backup doesn't?

Tags: tfs, backup

For various reasons, our support are backing up the TFS databases with their own tool, rather than using the built in TFS Scheduled Backup tool (we're using 2012 update 3).

I know the report encryption key is one thing that is also backed up using the tool.

Is there anything else the TFS tool backs up that I haven't mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TFS Backup wizard is the preferred way to do backups because it uses Marked Transactions to ensure a consistent backup set.  This is important because TFS data spans several databases (Collection + Config), and you need a way to ensure that the backups are consistent (from the same moment in time for all/both databases).

You can do this manually but it's tedious to setup.  You can see the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070.aspx

Comment: And sync the reports and Sharepoint backup with the data of TFS